# Can I use Qt for closed source commercial software?

Tags: commercial, closed-source

I am developing an application for geological research that I intend to sell for commercial purposes. With it I need a GUI too. I started using tkinter, but it seems to be, at least for me, somehow limited and does not support some of the core functions I need for the program (e.g. a MDI). Then I thought of Qt, which people say is very powerful, has lots of functions etc, but I am not sure about the "legal" aspect of it.

Basically I just want to know if I can use Qt (for free) to develop a closed-source, commercially distributed application?

Comment: Yes, as long as you don't include any GPLed Qt components in your product (as I recall, these are all clearly marked as such) and as long as you comply with the LGPL. You can find out more by looking for "LGPL" on this site. See also this Q&A which is nearly what you are asking here: https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/7414/can-someone-explain-the-basic-requirements-of-open-source-qt-lgpl-to-a-beginner

Answer (score 0):

Yes... though not quite.

First, Qt offers commercial and Open Source licenses.

Most often it's LGPL, but some parts of Qt are GPL-only or not FOSS licensed at all.
If your product only uses LGPL modules, you must meet the LGPL conditions, i.e. include the source of the Qt libraries. See the GNU (L)GPL FAQ [here](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html) or the Qt FAQ [here](https://www.qt.io/licensing/open-source-lgpl-obligations#lgpl).

If you use GPL modules, you must release the project's source code under the GPL license. Remember that binary files can still be sold, but anyone who gets the source code will be able to sell them further. There are strategies like paid support, but it's safer for you to just use the LGPL.

You can find a list of Qt modules [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtmodules.html). There is a section with GPL-only modules in the table. Or you can directly use this link.

It's worth saying that once you start working with Qt Open Source, you may have problems migrating to the commercial version and vice versa. However, Qt will help you with the migration, especially if you are migrating to a commercial version.

If you have any questions for me or have encountered a problem using GPL modules, you can ask me questions here, or if you wish, you can contact me directly if you do not want to publish certain information publicly.

**This is not legal/financial/business or any other advice.**

Comment: Are you sure the linked table has an overview of which ones GPL-only modules? When I look at the table, I do not see this information. One *can* click on a particular module to see if that one is GPL-only. For example, if I click "Qt Virtual Keyboard" (one that I know is GPL-only) then I see at the top of the page "Commercial or GPLv3" for that one. Most of the other modules' pages say nothing, so most likely that's an indication that it's LGPL (or Commercial, of course). In any case, if you want the definitive answer you'd need to unpack the source code of each module and read the LICENSE.